In-app-browser styling considering OAuth2 best practices
According to RFC8285 in-app-browsers are a best practice to meet the highest security standards when it comes to user authorization for mobile native apps using OAuth2. Based on experience, these in-app-browsers don't have a good Look & Feel for many technically uneducated users.
Going through my private mobile apps, I realized that  the apps of even FAANG companies don't look like using in-app-browsers. But I don't think they are using insecure WebViews either.
What are the possibilities to approach a WebView like Look & Feel in React Native while still using the in-app-browser?

Usually in OAuth you customize the authorization server's HTML login forms to build themes:

Web app 1 and mobile app 1 might share theme 1, eg with purple and white colours and fonts etc that match the app itself. With in app browsers you can also change navigation bar colours etc.

The end result should therefore look pretty much the same when the user leaves the app and not be too jarring for the user. Also, your app can present its own button and messaging to inform the user before you run the code flow.
How you write the HTML depends on the authorization server's web technology stack. Some of them might use modern options like React. You do the work once in the AS (not in your app) and can then reuse results in multiple applications.

Thanks, that's what I guessed. When there is no visible in-app-browser used, does it mean that the chance for Resource Owner Credentials Grant being used is high?
And a second thought on that: Would there be another layer of security if a dedicated backend service handled the communication with the authorization server? It would act as a confidential client instead of the public mobile client and receive username and password, handle the communication with the authorization server, and finally return the access token to the mobile client.

You shouldn't use the password grant. It is considered poor security. There are major advantages to using the code flow in terms of pluggable authentication behaviours and many ways to authenticate.

A BFF solves no security problems for a mobile client, since an attacker who impersonates your app or intercepts a token can use exactly the same endpoints your app does to call internet endpoints. There is still no client credential.

A better option is to use attestation features built into modern mobile devices to add security to calls to the token endpoint. They enable your app to send a digital signature that an attacker could not. Explaining that is outside the scope of your question though.
